# Issue with ftputil library and JPG-files

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, ftputil

I have code shown below

```
for root, dirs, files in ftp_host.walk(ftp_host.curdir, topdown=False):
    if ftp_host.path.isdir(root):
        for folder in ftp_host.path.normpath(root).split('/'):
            target_dir = os.path.join(target_dir, folder)
            if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
                os.mkdir(target_dir)

    for name in files:
        target_file = os.path.join(target_dir, name)
        # print name - I am able to see all files here including *.JPG  
        if ftp_host.path.isfile(name):
           # print name - there no any *.JPG  
           ftp_host.download(name, target_file)

    target_dir = curdir
```

When I am trying to download recursively all files from target FTP, but I can't any JPG's.

Please advice where I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... I dind't correct move to specific directory. ftputils work very well!